# htaccess to simulate multi-site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My web app has the following directory structure:

```
app_root/
    includes/
        config/
            db.php
            [other config files]
        [other include files]
    services/
        [various php files]
    templates/
        [html files]
    [js/, css/, images/ directories]
    index.php
```

Let's say I have one instance of the app under `/var/www/projects/abc/` meaning the app_root is `abc/`. This instance would be accessible with `http://host.com/projects/abc/`. Now, if I copy all files to `/var/www/projects/xyz/` and change the config files I would have a second instance accessible with `http://host.com/projects/xyz/`.

However, as the app gets bug fixes and feature implementations, changed files should be updated for all instances. To avoid this, I would like to have only the config files in peer instances; like this:

```
app_root/
    includes/
        config/
            db.php
            [other config files]
    .htaccess
```

This method leaves all common files in `abc` instance and only has instance-specific files in each peer.

I tried the following rules, but get 404 for requests I make:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/xyz/(.+)$ /abc/$1
```

I have `AllowOverride All` in my apache config and `.htaccess` rules are picked and applied otherwise. What am I missing?

**Update**

I realized that a parameter would need to be passed when accessing peer instances. So the objective is to rewrite:

http://host.com/projects/xyz/services/foo.php
to
http://host.com/projects/abc/services/foo.php?instance=xyz

Obviously `services/foo.php` is an arbitrary path.

Comment: Try removing the leading slash from **^/abc**

Comment: @starkeen Still getting 404.

Comment: What is full path of `app_root/`  and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: @anubhava Full path of main instance (with all files and *no* `.htaccess`): `/var/www/projects/abc/`. Full path of a peer instance (missing common files and with `.htaccess`): `/var/www/projects/xyz/`. Full path of `.htaccess` itself: `/var/www/projects/xyz/.htaccess`.

Comment: @anubhava the objective is to have `http://host.com/projects/xyz/services/foo.php` be redirected to `http://host.com/projects/abc/services/foo.php?instance=xyz`. The parameter passing is what I realized would be necessary after the question was posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule **inside `xyz/.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*) ../abc/$1?instance=xyz [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This did work, thank you. I changed the second line to `RewriteRule (.*) ../abc/$1?instance=xyz [L]` and had the `instance` parameter passed in as well.